# I want an image and text to aling along the bottom of my header div

Tags: css, alignment, fluid-layout

I have an img (logo hyperlink) and text (hyperlinks) in my header div. What I want is for the text and the bottom edge of the image to line up along the bottom of the div. Right now I have a 100px high img and 15px text and the text is aligned along the center horizontal of the image.

This is what my source code html looks like

```
</head>
<body bgcolor="#660099">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="header"> 
    <h1>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="graphics_home/mini_logo.jpg" alt="the white dove  woodstock"     width="159" height="99" border="0" align="absbottom" /></a>
 <a href="rooms.html" class="hlink">Rooms</a>  <a href="todo.html" class="hlink">ToDo</a>  <a href="about.html" class="hlink">About</a>  <a href="bloc.html"class="hlink">Blog</a>  <a href="shop.html" class="hlink">Shop</a>  <a href="reservations.html" class="hlink">Reservations</a> 
</h1>
  </div>
```

AND this is what my typography css looks like:

```
  #header h1{
    color: #cc0099;
    font-family: 'victor_moscosoregular', mono;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    word-spacing: .15 em; 
    }
    a.hlink:link {
    color: #cc0099;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
   a.hlink:hover {
    color: #cc99ff;
    }
```

ANY easy ideas how I should make everything "sit" along the bottom edge of the HeaderDiv?

I would post an image but they wont let me

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code out in a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YU6mw/1/

I added a `<br>` tag to make it go to the next line, I hope it worked!

Comment: Well Iappreciate you trying. Now imagine the image wasnt just a blue line of text but a 100px high image and the text is 15 px high. They are all aligning along the vertical alignment middle. I want them to align along the bottom of the image.

Comment: Ok I will see if I can fix it.

Comment: Also I tried to just add a vertical-align: bottom; command to the h1 but it didnt do anything to it even theough all items are inside the h1 classification

Comment: heres a link to the website file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/erincadigan/Documents/www.thewhitedoverockotel.com/index.html

Comment: That link does not work, it is a local file. I would suggest posting a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Honestly I have taught myself from scratch HTML on Dreamweaver and recently updated to DW6. It looks completely different plus I'm trying to build this website for my new hotel in Fluid Layout which seems to make certain commands just not work. I have NO IDEA what JSFiddle is. :( I have spent so much time just trying to get the bottom of the logo to align with the bottom of the text in the header. It's gotta be easier then this. sigh. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Dreamweaver is the same program I use! I will keep on trying.

Comment: you are a saint. Just do you understand what I'm trying to achieve? Here is a link to a diffeent website I built. See how the logo and the header links all align to the bottom? I have tried going back into my code from this website to copy the command but I cant figure out how I did it. I do rember having the same issue and resolving it though. http://www.threeerincadigan.com

Comment: I see, so you want it to be next to the logo? Or under? I am a bit confused now, before you said that it needed to be under.

Comment: can you post the link again?

Comment: no next to I said I wanted the bottom of the image and the bottom of the text to align along the bottom edge of the div

Comment: My first result did just that though? Which do you want, http://jsfiddle.net/YU6mw/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/YU6mw/2/ ?

Comment: okay this link jsfiddle.net/YU6mw/2 is the same exact code as my original code and it's not working. It works when viewing the image as text but not when a 100x150px image block is present then the text floats up to middle

Answer (score 0):

//do you mean like this

```
a:first-child{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    color:#fff;
 }
 a:hover{
    color:gold;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/PUvV9/2/

Comment: no i mean like the logo and header links here at www.threeerincadigan.com.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. As I am unfamiliar with the a. system you have used. Let me ask. What about other divs on the same page will this effect how elements are contained and displayed within their divs. Can I make these rules exclusive to the header? If so where would I put them in the css file? under the #header {} or in inside of it?

Comment: use direct child selector, my friend